# running a gatling simulation in cmd with mvn

Tags: maven, jenkins, gatling

im trying to run a gatling simulation in jenkins and i found out that i can run it in cmd with the command :
`mvn gatling:simulations.mySimulationName`
i already installed maven and gatling and when i use the mvn -v i get my version number but if i try to execute the command above i get this message :

`[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'gatling' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\myUser\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]`

i dont understand how do i install the gatling plugin into maven can someone help me with that?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, the `No plugin found for prefix 'gatling'` error means you haven't configured the `gatling-maven-plugin` in your maven project.

Then, your command is wrong, it should be `mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=simulations.mySimulationName`.

You should really take some time to read the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/extensions/maven_plugin/).

Moreover, you definitely can't use maven with something else than a maven project, in particular with a Gatling bundle. You have to move your test sources into the proper structure, eg [our official sample](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/extensions/maven_plugin/#demo-sample).

Comment: i dont have a maven project im just trying to run it in cmd from jenkins i dont have any maven projects ,the simulation is in the gatling folder and it was converted from HAR file with the recorder.bat file thats it.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What you're trying to do can't possible work. maven works only with maven projects.